# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot locate bin for temporary package: @angular/cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to update the Angular version of a project from 8 to 11 following this guide: https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=8.0-11.0. Updating to v9 has worked so far, however when running `ng update @angular/core@10 @angular/cli@10` I now get an error message and I can't find a post online to solve it.

```
The installed local Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable version.
Installing a temporary version to perform the update.
✔ Package successfully installed.
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot locate bin for temporary package: @angular/cli.
See "/private/var/folders/qy/0lhcj3516gb2hmdfcfj8jpf40000gn/T/ng-G8l2Tv/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The logs show the following

```
[error] Error: Cannot locate bin for temporary package: @angular/cli.
    at Object.runTempPackageBin (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/install-package.js:116:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async UpdateCommand.validateAndRun (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command.js:136:22)
    at async Object.runCommand (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:205:24)
    at async default_1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js:70:31)
```

I've tried "npm ci" to reinstall all node modules but I don't think that's helping. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

do this:

1. `sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
2. `sudo npm i -g @angular/cli@YOUR_LOCAL_VERSION` (take from *package.json* into your project)

if it didn't help - add **package.json** file data & **ng --version**

Answer (score 4):

Was upgrading from 12.0.0 to 12.0.1 and received the same error - upgrading/installing the global @angular/cli fixed it